# Creating new album for FB fan page via graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to create new album via graph api for the page that user manages. I have the `manage_pages` permission and I can upload single photos to page (FB collects them to the album with app name) and I believe that I can upload photos to album specified by id (as mentioned in documentation). But there is nothing about creating new album for pages via api calls. I've tried to use the way that describes how to create album for user:

```
$fb->api("/".$account->getAccountId()."/albums", "POST", array('name' => 'my new album'));
```

but this request returns me the following error message: `(#100) Invalid ID for album owner`. Is there any way to create an album for the FB page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make the call to POST the new album, you must use a PAGE access token.  You can get that page access token from the array returned when you call `me/accounts`.

You can try it in the Graph API Explorer tool:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: yes, of course I have access tokens for every page, because I cannot perform any required for me actions without it.

Comment: Does it work for you in the explorer tool?    Be sure to copy/paste the PAGE access token into the access token form field when you want to make the HTTP POST to the graph to add the album.

Comment: I've tried that way also, I've copy/pasted the right access token of page and it returns the same error. As there is nothing said about creating albums for page in docs (there is a way only to get the existing albums) I suppose that it's impossible, but I need to be sure to inform client that it's impossible

Comment: I've created many albums for pages in the past and I even tried it again when you asked your question (as Facebook loves changing stuff on us).  So it clearly is possible as of 40 minutes ago to add an album to a page.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support, I've tried via Graph API Explorer and it creates album now, I think the problem is in the permissions of my app. do I need any other permissions besides `manage_pages`?

Comment: Yes you do:  Please read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions